Oracle SQL: forcing all statements executed from my session to have their own "child_numbers"
I'm doing several tests using Oracle 19c and SQL Developer involving repeated executions of a set of statements and I would like to work in an isolated fashion, and so I want that the statements executed from my session doesn't share cursors with statements executed from other sessions.
Some statements are inside packages that I can't touch, and so my only choice is to change something in my session. Is there any "trick", any session parameter for example, that could cause Oracle to treat the statements executed from my session from now on as a different "execution context" and so forcing Oracle to hard parse the statements that are executed from now on?

Why would you want to do this? If you are trying to use v$sql counters to measure performance, you'd be better off using ASH (v$active_session_history) instead, which is already tied to your session. If you do have a reason to use v$sql counters (useful if you're concerned with milliseconds), changing a session parameter works quite well - that's a good enough trick without needing to find a better one. Or if the sql in question isn't being actively executed by others, you can simply obtain before/after counter values and subtract to find the difference attributable to your test.

However normally when we're tuning, we pull out the SQL from its natural setting (client code, package, etc...) and work with it ad-hoc. In that case, it's a simple matter of changing a bogus hint. E.g. select /*+ bogushint1 */ vs bogushint2, etc.. Even better, for sub-second queries you are tuning at the millisecond level, however, is simply timing it using a PL/SQL block that loops through a few hundred or thousand times and reports overall elapsed time using timestamp intervals. Rarely have I found a need to use v$sql counters for that kind of work.

@PaulW I checked and v$active_session_history stores samples, not all the statistics included in v$sql, right? Regarding modifying the query, some of the queries are "outside my control" so to speak (can't change it). And about changing session parameters, changing any session parameter would do the trick?

ASH stores 1-second wait sampling, which is the backbone of tuning. The only thing that really matters is how long a session spent doing something. The other metrics merely play a supportive role.  ASH is of course only useful for activity lasting more than a few seconds. If your queries are quicker than that, test them in bulk with a loop and time the whole set. Yes, changing any parameter will make your cursors non-sharable with others who have a different set of parameter values. You can even find an unimportant underscore parm and set it to literally anything. But it is not typical tuning.

For your "black box" packages, do they take some parameters?  You could use edge case  parms perhaps. Or same exact parameters and hit it a bunch of times... But you'd want to see how much time those calls take, compared to the other SQL you have control over....

@MarkStewart I just set parallel_min_time_threshold to increasing number per-test and since I know that none of my queries will be processed in parallel (our mode is manual and our tables are noparallel). That causes the optimizer environment to change and so cursors are never shared from queries executed before the last session change. I verified it by checking v$sql_shared_cursor (column optimizer_mismatch is Y and the reason column of the other child cursors even tells you which session parameters are different).

There's a lot of reasons why a statement will require its own child_cursor. Given an sql_id and a child_cursor, you can check the specific reason with:
select * from v$sql_shared_cursor where sql_id = '...';

There's a row per child_number and a column for each possible reason, and a value of Y or N indicating which reason caused the corresponding child_number to exists (if it doesn't exists, it means the statement matched another pre-existing child_number). If a new child_number is created, then the reason column of the last created child_number will tell you a textual description of the reason.
The most common causes a child_number is not shared are:

Queries come from different users
The statistics has changed and a new plan must be calculated (re-optimizing a query implies creating a new cursor).
The optimizer environment has changed, which basically means changing any parameter that COULD affect the optimizer, although it seems that in practice changing any session variable causes a cursor to not be shared.

I focused on the third reason. Since all my tables are noparallel (verified with select * from user_tables where degree != 1), I know none of my queries will be executed in parallel and hence I choose to change parallel_min_time_threshold to the amount of seconds that the instance has been running with select (sysdate - startup_time) * 86400 from v$instance.
If I do some select count(*) from table xxx, get the sql_id finding my query in v$sql, and executing the above select against v$sql_shared_cursor with such sql_id, I can see how new child_cursors are being created whenever I change the session variable, and how the before-the-last child_number will tell me the exact session parameter differences between that child_number and the newly created one. Creating a new child_number doesn't update all the reasons of all the previously existing child_cursors, only respect to the previous child, so you don't lose "historical information" about why older children were created.
